# Django server receives broken string data from Android Device that uses QR scanner(Keyboard input)

Tags: android, django, text

I am an Android App Developer.

And the app read QR code using QR Scanner device and get Token(a string) from it.

I send:

```
B8EurXd5xq9OsvcpGW
```

Server Log receives something like this:

```
B8
Eur
Xd5xq9
Osvcp
G
W
```

Is there a way to show \n, \r or something like that? I replaced them with `replace("\r", "")`, `replace("\n", "")` but didn't work.

More Info

I get keyboard input from QR Scanner device. It gets data one by one. So, I append til it has input data with `event.unicodeChar.toChar()`. And then when there's on input data,.

```
    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event == null) return false

        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER -> {
                if (barcode.length > 10) {
                    // TODO: call API
                    login(barcode.toString())
                    Log.d("qrcode", barcode.toString()) // this shows properly.
                }
                barcode = StringBuilder("")
            }
            else -> {
                barcode.append(event.unicodeChar.toChar())
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```

Comment: How are you sending/receiving the data? Can you share examples?

Comment: I added more info, please check.